# Prettier VSCode. Single Quotes set, yet ALWAYS changes it to double

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

1. Using `Prettier` extension in VSCode.
2. Have the `Single Quote` set to single.
3. `format onSave` is set to true.

***Still...***
When I hit save, single quotes are converted to double..

WHY? WHY? WHY? WHY?

---

In addition...

1. I've set eslint to use single quotes
2. I've even deleted the eslint extension from VSCode.

```
// in .eslint file
"quotes": [2, "single", { "avoidEscape": true }],
```

***Still...***
When I hit save, single quotes are converted to double..

### WHYYYY?

Answer (score 6):

I've traced the source of the problem.

It appears there are levels of configuration that will be checked when VSCode attempts to reformat the text when `format on save` is checked.

- Prettier extension config
- `.eslintrc`
- `.editorconfig`

I'm still not sure in what order they run in, thus who has the final say.

But in my case, a VERY basic `.editorconfig` was the problem. Deleting this file fixed it.

```
# EditorConfig https://editorconfig.org/

root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

In the file above there is no mention of spacing prefs at all. So I'm assuming there are some defaults to double quotes.

Comment: This is a little old now, but I was able to update `.editorconfig` to include single quotes instead of deleting it (it was required by my employer, in my case):

`quote_type = single`

Comment: @ZacSeth now I have the opposite problem.. all quote are turned to single quotes :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. make sure if prettier is using any other config that could override it's own settings in VSCode. most likely to be `.editorconfig`

there's two options

1. still use `.editorconfig`

Add this code in `.editorconfig`

```
quote_type = single
```

2. stop using `.editorconfig`

In `.vscode/settings.json`, add this code.

```
"prettier.useEditorConfig": false, // tell prettier to don't use .editorconfig

"prettier.singleQuote": true, // force single quote
```